# Why can't I type [ ] opening and closing brackets on the Visual tab?

Tags: shortcode, tinymce

Trying to type [ brings the text area to full screen. Trying to type ] does nothing. It really inhibits my shortcode usage. On the Text tab it works fine, so it's only in TinyMCE. I use an european keyboard layout where unlike US layouts we don't have a dedicated button for coding characters. I have to press Alt Gr + F or Alt Gr + G for these brackets, and they seem to conflict with some kind of keyboard shortcut I didn't even set up. How can I get rid of that key binding?

Comment: To me your question is Too localized, because WordPress doesn't provide such key bindings ([screenshot](http://prntscr.com/7btuse)). I think the keyboard layout you are using, is somehow conflicting with TinyMCE javascripts.

Comment: But I remember it was working some time ago. If I disable all plugins/theme, switch browser from Firefox to Chrome, same thing. I'm sometimes able to write ] but never [.